# How to check if a vector contains an unordered sequence of numbers from 1 to N

Tags: r

I'm looking to check if a vector of data is in rank form. That is; each observations is a number between 1 and N, where N is the number of observations, but in a random, unknown order.

The simplest check I could think of was the gaussian sum, using (N * (N + 1)) / 2 and comparing that to the sum of the vector. Except in my case I have 200,000 observations and the sum of all numbers from 1 to 200,000 is greater than 2^32. Apart from getting a 64 bit computer what is the fastest method of checking that data is in rank form.

Comment: Your gaussian sum check will return a false positive if you have two values whose diff cancel each other, e.g. it would return true for 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6 (where 2 is decreased by 1 and 4 is increased by 1) and N = 6.

Comment: As a previous deleted comment noted setdiff(1:N, vector) appears to work. Though I'm not sure how to deal with return type of integer(0) quite yet. @FrankSchmitt It might return a false positive but the data very unlikely to be in a form close to that of ranks. It will either be ranked or not.

Comment: Also what's with all the downvotes, should I just delete the question?

Comment: I guess downvotes for the lack of working example. Supply some example rather than verbal description.

Comment: `length(unique(x))==length(x)&is.integer(x)`

Comment: Thanks very much Khashaa. That line is a full second faster than setdiff().

Answer (score 0):

```
checkForRanks <- setdiff(1:N,X)
isRanked <- length(checkForRanks) > 0
if(!isRanked) stop("Please rank data")
```